# getting node.js to send buffer as a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, nginx, download

I'm trying to create an excel workbook on the server side that is send to the user when they visit a certain route (using express.js)
I'm using the module from https://github.com/riyadhalnur/excelbuilderjs-node
and I do have a large chunk of data in the `workBookB64` constant, and in my browser (chrome) I do get both headers for disposition and content type after the `res.end()` call.  **BUT** the file is never downloaded on the browser side.
I have my node process running behind an Nginx reverse proxy, to handle the SSL.
Any ideas on how to get the file to download would be great!

```
    const result      = Excel.createFile( workBook );
    const workBookB64 = new Buffer( result, 'base64' );

    res.setHeader( 'Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName );
    res.setHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64' );
    res.end( workBookB64 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this on my own.  It turns out that the issue was in how I was requesting the URL.  The client side code was using a jQuery call:
`$.get("/getReport")` so the response was going back to this call, which had no callback handler.  So to me it appeared as if it wasn't working.
The solution I used was to eliminate the JS, and just use an anchor tag, and call the URL directly.